# XCode : Number pad with point for comma

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikeyboard, numpad

I have a number pad with done button.  But the user can only choose numbers without commas. Is there a way to have a number pad with donebutton (which I have), integrated with punctuation, or at least a point for the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question implies that you're doing to be doing some formatted number.  It would then seem like a safe assumption that you're going to be working with a fixed number of decimal places (as it is more common to see a formatted number with a fixed number of decimal places than without).

If this is true, then you don't need the <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>,</kbd> buttons at all.  You could just start with the fixed number of decimal places and shift stuff over.  For example, let's say you want to type the number "4,238.07".

```
______.__  //type 4
______._4  //type 2
______.42  //type 3
_____4.23  //type 8
____42.38  //type 0
___423.80  //type 7
_4,238.07
```